# Foreign key refering to primary keys across multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql

i have three tables say city,state and road

1) city -> city_id(PK),name

2) state-> Stt_id(PK),name

3) Road-> Edge_id(PK), Admin_id(FK)

where Admin_id refers to city_id and Stt_id both.

This is done because the tables are too huge.

say city_id contains 1,2,3
and Stt_id contains 4,5,6

now if i am inserting 1,2,3,4,5,6 in admin_id it is throuing an error .. what is the solution of my problem,

regards

sanjay

Answer (score 1):

Create an `admin` table that holds an entry for every city and state, using its `admin_ids` as `city_id` and `stt_id` in their respective tables. Then declare foreign keys on `city_id`, `stt_id` and `road.admin_id`, referencing `admin.admin_id` (retaining all the existing PKs, of course).